# Typing activity is preventing retryPrompt activity from showing up

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a simple question answering bot based on V4 template, I have a prompt that asks for password, if the password is wrong it retries by asking again.

It works fine until I add the typing activity to give the user some feedback while waiting, in that case, the retryPrompt doesn't show the text anymore (But it's still working, if you type the right password it will go on as expected)

At this moment I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or I just hit a bug.

I've tried creating the prompt in different ways and creating the typing activity inside a dialog but there's been no luck.

The auth prompt inside a dialog:

```
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions
            {
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Incorrect password. Please try again."),
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please, enter the password")
            };

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("LoginPrompt", promptOptions, cancellationToken);
```

The typing activity code:

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var activity = turnContext.Activity;

            Activity isTypingActivity = activity.CreateReply();
            isTypingActivity.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(isTypingActivity);

            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Expected result:

Bot->Please, enter the password  
 
User->WrongPassword   
B->Incorrect password. Please try again.   
U->CorrectPassword   
B->Welcome

Actual result:

B->Please, enter the password
U->WrongPassword
U->RandomPassword
U->¿Are you broken?
U->CorrectPassword
B->Welcome

I get the expected result if I remove the typing activity code, so it seems like that code is preventing the retryPrompt from being sent or shown. But I have no clue what's going on.

Comment: Are you sending that typing activity back from within the current dialog that's using the prompt?

Comment: No, I'm sending it from the ActivityHandler

Comment: So that would send back a typing activity on every response sent in from the user? You could move it into a middleware service which might be a better approach if that was your plan.

Comment: Yeah that's the plan, good idea, I'm going to try that